I get grub rescue when I try to boot PC
I had Windows 7 and Lubuntu together. I decided to replace Lubuntu with Ubuntu, and deleted the partition it was on. I created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 24 desktop, and started the installation.
During the installation the boot hung at one stage, and nothing happened for a long time. After I restarted the PC, I saw grub rescue
and I tried to fix the situation with different solutions from the Internet, but it did not help. As a result, at the moment I have Windows 7, which cannot be launched, a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu, which will not install it (but can launch a trial version), and grub rescue, which is shown when I start the computer without a USB stick.
I understand that I acted very stupidly and made a lot of mistakes.
Is it possible to somehow fix the situation?
If yes, how to do it?

The easiest way is to install again. If the automatic install hangs again - do not shutdown! Instead open a terminal and read the last lines of "journalctl".
Paste relevant errors into your question.
It could be that 24.04 is too new for your hardware, considering your Windows 7 and Lubuntu (which is the right choice for old hardware btw)
Since grub is about the lastest to be installed, you need to go through the installing process.
Update
Your short error message indicates a problem with your network. Or your RAM is too small, since the image is taken from /tmp. See here

If your system is Windows 7, which is obsolete and an old BIOS/MBR system, Ubuntu may be too much system. I could not install Ubuntu on my 2006 BIOS system, but server & Kubuntu did install. Only really became functional with Kubuntu on external SSD as old slow internal HDD and limited RAM going to swap was very slow.

Thanks to you, I believed in installing Ubuntu, and it did!
But note, the installation always got stuck for several hours (until I terminated the process early) at this stage "acquiring and extracting image from cp...".
Once again, thank you very much, you really helped me out before the big day!
